# How to animate png image

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, keyframe

Tried this but not working. How can i animate it ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

.Animate1 {
animation:mymove 5s 2;
-webkit-animation:mymove 5s 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
}


@keyframes mymove
{
0%   {top:0px;}
25%  {top:200px;}
75%  {top:50px}
100% {top:100px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {top:0px;}
25%  {top:200px;}
75%  {top:50px}
100% {top:100px;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<img class="Animate1" src="http://static.monstermmorpg.com/images/monsters-images-240-240/72-Wogare.png"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to use top,left,right,bottom property you must have to set **position** property either **absolute,relative or fixed**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `top/left/bottom/right` properties without also positioning the `<img>` - you'll need to position it within the `.Animate1` selector. I added absolute positioning in the below fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FZhJ9/1/

You  can also use the `translateX()/translateY()` functions which serve the same purpose (if you don't want to position the `<img>`)

http://jsfiddle.net/FZhJ9/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just change as below in your .Animate1 Class css :

```
.Animate1 {
   animation:mymove 5s 2;
   -webkit-animation:mymove 5s 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
    position:absolute;
}
```

You can also use position as relative or fixed depend on your requirement.

to use **top,left,right,bottom** property you must have to set **position** property either **absolute,relative or fixed**